# Update Statement with ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY... ORDER BY)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to write an update statement using ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY... ORDER BY)

Here is a sample of my table:

```
ROW_NO   ENTITY_ID   ENTITY_NAME   EFF_DATE     INSURANCE_CO   SCENARIO_ID   
1        352725      ABC COMPANY   10/20/2000   999            NULL
2        352732      ABC COMPANY   7/1/2002     888            NULL
3        352736      ABC COMPANY   8/6/2004     999            NULL
4        865867      ABC COMPANY   10/16/2007   888            NULL
```

I used ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ENTITY_NAME ORDER BY EFF_DATE ASC) 'ROW_NO' to get the ROW_NO

What I'd like to do is set SCENARIO_ID = 1 where INSURANCE_CO = 999 of the previous row.

Here are the results I'm trying to achieve:

```
ROW_NO   ENTITY_ID   ENTITY_NAME   EFF_DATE     INSURANCE_CO   SCENARIO_ID   
1        352725      ABC COMPANY   10/20/2000   999            NULL
2        352732      ABC COMPANY   7/1/2002     888            1
3        352736      ABC COMPANY   8/6/2004     999            NULL
4        865867      ABC COMPANY   10/16/2007   888            1
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: So, what do you have? Why isn't it working as you expect?

Comment: Why do you want to update the table with a value you can always calculate at runtime? It just means you'll always have to keep it up to date _for all rows_ whenever _any row_ is changed. This is wasteful unless you are reading that value a whole lot more than you are updating anything in this table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update based on previous record, lead function will help instead of row_number

```
SELECT LEAD( 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY ENTITY_NAME  ,INSURANCE_CO
        ORDER BY EFF_DATE
    ) ,*
    FROM Table_name 
    ORDER BY  ROW_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

With LAG() window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LAG(INSURANCE_CO) OVER(PARTITION BY ENTITY_NAME ORDER BY EFF_DATE ASC) prev
  FROM tablename
)
UPDATE cte
SET SCENARIO_ID = 1
WHERE prev = '999'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7d8e4916902a1e87733536a7a623a9c).
Results:

```
> ROW_NO | ENTITY_ID | ENTITY_NAME | EFF_DATE                | INSURANCE_CO | SCENARIO_ID
> -----: | --------: | :---------- | :---------------------- | -----------: | :----------
>      1 |    352725 | ABC COMPANY | 2000-10-20 00:00:00.000 |          999 | null       
>      2 |    352732 | ABC COMPANY | 2002-07-01 00:00:00.000 |          888 | 1          
>      3 |    352736 | ABC COMPANY | 2004-08-06 00:00:00.000 |          999 | null       
>      4 |    865867 | ABC COMPANY | 2007-10-16 00:00:00.000 |          888 | 1
```